# $('#select').val() returns UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some jQuery code, this is a part of it. this always return **UNDEFINED**. why is that

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="theme/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#my").click(function() {
        alert($("#adults").val());
    });
 }); 

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<a href="#" id="my">click</a>
<select class="text" id="currency" id="adults">
    <option value="1"  selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" >3</option>
    <option value="4" >4</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is used to get how many adults are there. Can't run without it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use **id** attribute two times on one node (in fact id values should be unique across one html page). In your case use either *currency* or *adults*.

If you get rid of extra `id="currency"` jQuery will return correct value using expression `$("#adults").val()`.

Answer (score 2):

You gave your select element two `id` attributes.  Remove one and it should work perfectly.

```
<select class="text" id="currency" id="adults">
```

becomes

```
<select class="text" id="adults">
```

The `id` attribute should always be unique.  If you want to give more than one element the same "identifier" so that you can retrieve a group of elements, then you should give it a `class` attribute instead.

When you gave two `id` attributes, the code doesn't know which one to use and this can lead to unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned an element two IDs. Please remove the first one as the ID [must be unique](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id).

Answer (score 0):

hey u cannot use two ids i.e.  `id="currency"` and `id="adults"` at the same time...delete `id="currency"` and you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ids in the select tag, so the second won't work.

`<select class="text" id="currency" id="adults">`

Answer (score 0):

Your select has 2 ID's. You can't do that. You can add more then one class to an object, or use the same class for more then one objects, but ID's can be used only one per object, and only one object per id.

```
<select class="text" id="currency" id="adults">
```